# Rigidbody moves automatically

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am doing hand-tracking in Unity and am using localPosition to update the positions of the joints. To make the hand rigid, I added a Rigidbody to root of the hierarchy. But when I do so, the hand starts to move on its own... Is there any way to make it stay in place, without restricting the Rigidbody constraints or setting Kinematics to true (since I still want it to avoid going through other objects)? Any help is appreciated!

Below is a video of this occurring (the hand flies off as soon as I press play): 
https://youtu.be/GiT1bv-Zp_M

Comment: Disable **"Use Gravity"**

Comment: Uncheck "use gravity."

Comment: Use gravity was unchecked at the time I ran the program. Might it have something to do with the fact the the child transforms are moving which is  applying some kind of force on the root transform (which contains the Rigidbody component)?